# Menubar's abstract description

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, abstraction

I want to create some description of menu bars (items and connected with them actions-object or handler's-methods) with some abstraction from gui library. In what way I can do it?

some draft

data structure (without access methods and other stuff):

```
public class MenuInfoHolder {
    List<Column> menu;

    public static class Column {
        SimpleItem title;
        List<Block> blocks;
    }
    public static class SimpleItem{
        String title;
        char key;
    }
    public static class Block{
        List<SimpleItem> items;
    }   
    public static abstract class ActionProducedItem extends SimpleItem { 
        abstract void invokeActionHandler(ActionHandler handler);
    }
}
```

and here might be some using, like

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
ActionProducedItem item = new ActionProducedItem("Aaaa", 'a'){
    @Override
    void invokeActionHandler(ActionHandler handler) {
        handler.foo();
    }
};
Block block = new Block();
block.add(item);
Column column = new Column("BBB", 'B');
column.add(block);
menu.add(column);
```

Does exist any other better implementation (probably with Builder pattern or spring framework)?

UPD:
another worlds,

using SWT, smt like:

```
final Menu popupMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.CASCADE);
menuItem.setText("More options");
Menu subMenu = new Menu(menuItem);
menuItem.setMenu(subMenu);
...
shell.setMenuBar(menu);
```

using Swing, smt like:

```
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();                
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);        
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
```

But in both case we operate with same data. So I want make some abstraction about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your examples don't really make it clear what you're trying to accomplish (to me anyway).  Can you go into better detail what your goals are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to Use Actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is all that comes to mind.

Comment: I want do some abstraction of menu structure. I can't do it only with actions.